# Why would a solr search be limited to 5 characters?

Tags: solr

When querying for the term "population" on a field called text:

```
.../solr/select?q=text:(pop*)
```

returns results that contain the word "population".

However, if there are more then 5 characters before the asterisks, nothing is returned:

```
.../solr/select?q=text:(popula*)
```

This however works:

```
.../solr/select?q=text:(population)
```

As does this (I have no idea why):

```
.../solr/select?q=text:(popul)
```

Without the asterisks only 5 characters works and full text works.

It is not limited to "population", the same seems to apply to other words (I tried "numerator").

Why is there a limit of 5 characters?

I have not changed much from the version of solr I down loaded.

The field "text" has a type "text_en_splitting".

"text_en_splitting" has two analyzers, one of type "index", and one of type "query".  I haven't touched either of them.

The query analyzer looks like this:

```
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
```

The index analyzer looks the same, but is missing the "solr.SynonymFilterFactory" filter.

Answer (score 0):

try the [Analysis](http://your.host:8983/solr/admin/analysis.jsp?highlight=on) page to debug how that query is being analyzed, will be much easier to see the issue then. But it might be caused by the PorterStemFilter, try removing it.

Answer (score 0):

The [Porter stemmer](http://qaa.ath.cx/porter_js_demo.html) stems `population populous popul popula popular` to `popul popul popul popula popular`

So `population` and `popul` share stem, but not with `popula`.

If you want searches of the type you specified, use the `string` datatype. Please search the "string vs text in Solr" questions on this site.